# How to efficiently clean bathroom's toilet and tiles, so the dirt/urine from one area doesn't soil the other?

Tags: bathroom, cleaning

I've recently started to live on my own (with some roommates), and I'm big on cleanliness, and cleaning the bathroom is a nightmare.  I start with the counter top and bathtub next, both go well enough, but it's the toilet bowl that is a nightmare because it's not self contained like the tub.  Every time I pour a bit of water on the toilet bowl (the sides), it naturally pours down on the tile.  That's really urine water going down to the tiles.  Solution?  I use bit of detergent on more urine soaked spots and use a cloth to run with just couple of drops of water, and only then pour some more water, but still, that would still contain some urine mixed with water.

Same problem with tiles.  As you know, guys rarely get their pee in the toilet bowl (I guess I'm the exception) so the tiles are the same story.  Pouring water just spreads the filth.  I end up using gloves and going through a lot of pieces of cloth to do the job.

I know I'm being a bit OCD, so I appreciate sensitive replies and constructive solutions, so I can find a compromise between excellent time-consuming cleanliness and efficient use of time and resources.  Just to let you know, I use gloves, Tide detergent, and some pieces of cloths, that's all.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your a bit OCD I almost hate to post any thing but it never hurts to do a good cleaning and a good occasional disinfecting of the bathroom.  As long as it does not get over done as the items used to clean and disinfect  can be harmful in there own right if exposed beyond need.  [disinfecting](http://www.geeksonhome.com/info_8303666_difference-between-cleaning-disinfecting.html)
The markets are full of many good working bathroom spray on cleaners and disinfectants, a lite spray and then a damp wipe should be good for daily use.

Comment: Another over looked way to disinfect is with hydrogen peroxide and water solution. Some hospitals use this because it dosent have the odor of bleach.+

Comment: Thanks Ed, appreciate the suggestion, bleach smell can be quite powerful.